# React-Native: Display JSON Data

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```js
   
function getData(access_token) {
  fetch('https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/activities/steps/date/today/1m.json', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
    },
    // body: `root=auto&path=${Math.random()}`
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      console.log(`res: ${JSON.stringify(res)}`);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('Error: ', err);
    });
}
export default class App extends Component {
  
  connectFitbit = () => {
    OAuth(client_id, getData);
  };

  render() {
    
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to Fitbit Integration</Text>
        <Button title="connect fitbit" onPress={() => this.connectFitbit()} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get fit bit steps JSON data in react native app ,
right now I am getting the output in console ,now i want to parse the step data in my app please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display your data in to flatlist...

First you need to make array for saving your response data..

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     ...
      result: [],
     ...
    };
  }

function getData(access_token) {
  fetch('https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/activities/steps/date/today/1m.json', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
    },

  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      console.log(`res: ${JSON.stringify(res)}`);
      // if your response have anu json array
        this.setState({
            result:res.data,
          });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('Error: ', err);
    });
}
```

After, in flatlist simply set this array,

```
<FlatList
      data={this.state.result}
        renderItem={item => your render view}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => your key item}/>
```